# form field is not stored in mysql database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have created a simple form consisting of a textarea field, so when user clicks on submit button its linked to a jquery script containing a url executing the process and store the data, but problem is every time i hit submit, ID & created_at data is stored but the data given on textarea is ignored and not stored, never faced this problem before..please help me out!

**HTML**

```
<form id="form" name="form" method="POST" action="profile_1.php" class="wizard-big" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data" required="">
    <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
        <textarea type="text" name="status" id="status" placeholder="What's on your mind.." class="form-control" style="height:100px;"></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
        <input style="width:100%" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Post" class="btn btn-success">
    </div>

</form>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit").click(function(e) {

        var status = $('form')[0].checkValidity();
        if (status) {
            var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);

            $.ajax({
                url: "form_post.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: formData,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                async: false,
                dataType: "JSON",

                success: function(json) {
                    if (json.error) {
                        alert(json.error_msg);
                        e.preventDefault();
                    } else {
                        alert("Post updated successfully!");
                    }
                },

                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(errorThrown);
                }
            });
        }

    });
});
```

**php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    define('HOST','localhost');
    define('USER','**');
    define('PASS','**');
    define('DB','**');

    $response = array();

    $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('Unable to Connect');

    if(!mysqli_connect_errno()){

        $error_flag = false;
        /*foreach($_POST as $value){
            if(empty($value)){
                $error_flag = true;
                break;
            }
        }*/

        if(!$error_flag){

            //receiving post parameters
          $status =$_POST['status'];


          // create a new user profile
          $sql = "INSERT INTO status (via, status, created_at) VALUES ('".$_SESSION['vault_no']."', '$status', NOW())";

            if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
                $response["error"] = false;
                $response['via'] = $via;
                echo json_encode($response);
            }else{
                $response["error"] = true;
                $response["error_msg"] = "INSERT operation failed";
                echo json_encode($response);
            }
        }else{
            $response["error"] = true;
            $response["error_msg"] = "Few fields are missing";
            echo json_encode($response);
        }

    }else{
        $response["error"] = true;
        $response["error_msg"] = "Database connection failed";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Have you checked in your browser's network console that AJAX call is executing? Make sure it sends the correct form data and also did you try to debug `$_POST` in your .php file?

Comment: check what ajax success is return?

Comment: okay..!! i'll check that!

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` data directly into a query.

Comment: ajax is returning a success message "Post updated successfully!" everytime i hit submit

Comment: Are you sure you have a single form on this page or if have multiple then this one you are trying to submit is the first form?

Comment: Exactly..!! spotted, yes sir am having multiple forms in a single page but i have made sure all are having distinct names and ID's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note: The solution is in the comments for other readers of this question**

Maybe this helps you out. You need to change it to your wish offcourse

And save this function, it could be usefull for you in the future.

This function serializes the form as how it should be done.

```
<script>
$.fn.serializeObject = function()
{
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function() {
        if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return o;
};

$(function() {
    $('form').submit(function() {
        var formData = $('form').serializeObject();
        $.ajax({
            data: formData,
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'form_post.php',
            success: function(result) {
                $('#result').html(result);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert(textStatus); }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you! Sir, seems an interesting script to me but its not helping me sadly!

Comment: You used the function serializeObject instead of new Formdata?

Comment: yes sir, i did use your script..!! but the vital issue which am facing now is i have mentioned "required" for that textarea, but even that is ignored and is not poping up any kind of required! message if user is directly hitting submit without any data.!

Comment: try to change `$('form')[0]` to `$("#status")`

Comment: sorry, sir but its not working!! but thanks a ton for guiding me out!

Comment: What's the result when you change the succes function to `success: function(json) { alert(json); },`?

Comment: Its directly jumping on to else condition and executing it!

Comment: Delete the else function for the moment. Display result in a alert. The result is in the variabele 'json'.

Comment: OR you can change `alert("Post updated successfully!");` temporarily to `alert(json);` and then try and see result

Comment: Now its popping up alert as [object Object] dont know what it is?

Comment: That means that the return data (in the returned json variabele) is on object ;) :P

Comment: change now `alert(json);` to `alert(json.error);` and see if it returns true or false (i expect that it returns false)

Comment: ya..exactly it should and it returned false.!

Comment: So now im pretty sure that the `$_POST['status']` variabele is empty. Because your PHP code is okay (except for the sql injection possibility)

Comment: ye, sir got the required answer sir but...sitill the question remained unanswered that even though i have specified " required="" " in <form> tag why it accepting a empty field as it is..??

Comment: `<textarea type="text" name="status" id="status" placeholder="What's on your mind.." class="form-control" style="height:100px;" required></textarea>` no quotes and in the input/textfield, not in the form tag. But anyway, the problem is in sending the data with jquery, not in the "empty" textarea

Comment: The line under `var formData = ....` place an alert like `alert(formData.get());` and check what it returns after submit

Comment: No sir..! even that is resolved:-) and thanks for correcting that silly mistake of  mine!

Comment: How to add multiple form in a single HTML page as similar method    as above using Jquery ajax..?? would be okay if any helpful reference given.. coz i've gone through many but could not find a optimal solution

Comment: use `$('#formID').submit(function() { /* ajax here */ }` and give the `<form>` tag an ID field